# Headphones not working on Model 3 B (retropie)

Tags: audio, retropie

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 model B and am using Retropie.

I have it connected to to portable display, but when I plug in headphones, I get no audio.

Any help will be much appreciated, and I will answer questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect the hdmi first, it will use the hdmi as the audio output.

Try connecting the audio jack first.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi organisation has some detailed pages to help with Audio problems:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/audio/

In summary:
First download the example MP3 file using the following command in terminal:

```
wget http://rpf.io/lamp3 -O example.mp3 --no-check-certificate
```

> To play an MP3 file, navigate to the location of the .mp3 file in the terminal using  cd and then type the following command:

```
omxplayer example.mp3`
```

> This will play the audio file `example.mp3` through either your monitor's built-in speakers or your headphones, connected via the headphone jack.
>
> If you cannot hear anything, make sure your headphones or speakers are connected correctly. Note that omxplayer doesn't use ALSA and so ignores the audio configuration set by `raspi-config` or `amixer`.
>
> If your HDMI monitor or TV has built-in speakers, the audio can be played over the HDMI cable

Try connecting your Pi to a HDMI monitor or TV that can also output sound. See if this works.

> If omxplayer's auto-detection of the correct audio output device fails, you can force output over HDMI with:

```
omxplayer -o hdmi example.mp3
```

> Alternatively, you can force output over the headphone jack with:

```
omxplayer -o local example.mp3
```

> You can even force output over both the headphone jack and HDMI with:

```
omxplayer -o both example.mp3
```

> Right-clicking the volume icon on the desktop taskbar brings up the audio output selector; this allows you to select between the internal audio outputs. It also allows you to select any external audio devices, such as USB sound cards and Bluetooth audio devices. A green tick is shown against the currently selected audio output device — simply left-click the desired output in the pop-up menu to change this. The volume control and mute operate on the currently selected device.

If that doesn't work...

> The following command, entered in the command line, will switch the audio output to HDMI:
>
> `amixer cset numid=3 2`
>
> Here the output is being set to 2, which is HDMI. Setting the output to 1 switches to analogue (headphone jack). The default setting is 0 which is automatic.